# MySQL: Error while loading the configuration and product catalog

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL Community Server installed on my system. It is working fine but everyday at 12:00 AM (or when connecting to the internet after 12:00 AM) there is a pop up that checks for somethings and closes by itself.

But after the latest windows update, it is not closing by itself and rather gets terminated with an error code. I checked and the CLI works fine for me but I want to suppress this error message.

Here's the complete error message:

```
=================== Start Initialization =================== 
MySQL Installer is running in Community mode
Initializing product requirements. 
Loading product catalog. 
Checking for product packages in the bundle. 
Categorizing product catalog. 
Finding all installed packages.

There was an error encountered while loading the configuration and 
product catalog: Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\settings-Community.xml' is denied. 
Initialization failed. Please check the logs for more information.

[process exited with code 2 (0x00000002)]
```

Kindly help!

PS: I use Windows 11 and MySQL 8.0 Community Server

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry for that. I will edit the question

Comment: @AryanSoni *Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\settings-Community.xml' is denied.*  is the folder `MySQL Installer for Windows` created by `MySQL` or manually ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha It was created by MySQL. And initially there was no problem but after latest windows update, this started to happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved by providing `full control` to the file named `settings-Community.xml`. By default it was only `read/write` but after changing it in `/properties/security`, the error message disappeared.